# Can recurrences involving $\gcd$ be solved?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can recurrences of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i=\gcd(n, X_n)
$$

Where $a_i$ are constant coeficients.
$a_i,X_i$ are integers. $a_n\neq0$.

For $n \geq 2$ be solved?

Here is an example:

$$
X_n=X_{n-1}+\gcd(n, X_{n-1}). X_1=7
$$

This example produces only prime numbers, and recurrences like this arose in some exercises I was working on. I want to know if a closed form is possible.

Comment: Integers, sorry, I added that in.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like it would be very hard to find $a_i$ for which the solution even *exists*. Do you have any non-trivial example?

Comment: @tomasz: If most of the $a_i$s are $0$, then there may be plenty of solutions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: This is why I asked for *non-trival* examples. If almost all $a_i$ are zero, then the right hand side is eventually constant, and thus must be equal to one (because there are infinitely many primes).

Comment: Anyway, if *any* $a_i$ is zero, and there are any solutions, there are infinitely many of them.